# Crashpad_handler consuming extremely high amounts of CPU

Tags: macos, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, cpu, crash-reports

I believe crashpad_handler creates and uploads crash reports and that there are multiple software that make use of it. In my case, it comes from VS code, location:

/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Resources/**crashpad_handler**

I have never seen such high CPU consumption, my Macbook Air becomes extremely noisy.

I am tempted to just delete the "crashpad_handler" unix executable, however, I fear that in the future if my program ever crashes I might not be able to get help from technical support since none of my crash reports will have been uploaded.

This seems to be quite a common issue, however, I have not seen any thread regarding this here.

Kindly suggest how can I fix this issue once and for all (not just force quit it in the activity monitor since I'll have to do that every time).

Thank you.